# Cannot open file in matlab where file path is stored as string

Tags: file, matlab, file-io

I am trying to open a file in matlab where the filename is stored as a String. My source code is

```
strSensor={'AF3','F7','F3','FC5','T7','P7','O1','O2','P8','T8','FC6','F4','F8','AF4'};
[rowsS,colsS]=size(strSensor);
for x=1:colsS
    str02=strcat(str01,strSensor(x));
    str02=strcat(str02,'.txt');
    str02
    fid=fopen(str02,'at');
    fprintf(fid,sumf(col));
end
```

The initial value of str01 is

```
str01='D:\Dropbox\data\';
```

It get's concatenated by a value given from the user, a slash (\) and then the rest of the array so I can access the files

The error I get is

```
Error using fopen
First input must be a file name of type char, or a file identifier of
type double.

Error in sensorprocessing (line 35)
    fid=fopen(str02,'at');
```

I am using Matlab2013a

I printed the value of str02 and it is

```
str02 =  'D:\Dropbox\data\alpha\AF3.txt'
```

**EDIT
I figured out why the array started from the end, I did not have X in the loop but I had colsS. So that was fixed. The file stil cannot be read though.

Comment: What is the value of `str02` when you get the error?

Comment: Have you tried to print `str02`? What are `str01` and `colsS` values?

Comment: Edited my post with more information

Comment: Try `strSensor{x}` instead of `strSensor(x)` to get the sensor string, not a cell element containing it.

Comment: @s.bandara Thanks it was fixed. Please type it as answer so you can get your due credit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside the loop where you concatenate the file name, you index the sensor names with parentheses as in `strSensor(3)`, which yields a cell array with one element.

`strcat` will not complain since it can operate on cells. However, this also means that `strcat` will return `str02` also as a cell array. You can convince yourself with

```
>> class(str02)
ans = cell
```

To really get at the content of a cell array, you index it with curly braces. If you use `strSensor{x}` you will be working with the string content and `fopen` will stop complaining about input types.